# How to find the number of emails sent to a single domain within this entire year by creating SQL Query for salesforce

Tags: sql, salesforce

I am using this below and it is not pulling data once automation is created.

```
SELECT j.EmailName, s.EmailAddress, s.SubscriberKey, se.JobID, se.EventDate
 from _Job j INNER JOIN _Sent se on j.JobID = se.JobID  
                    INNER JOIN _Subscribers s ON se.SubscriberKey = s.SubscriberKey 
WHERE s.SubscriberKey = 'exclaim-dev.com' 

and se.EventDate > '2018-01-01'
```

Comment: `GROUP BY` and `COUNT()`?

Comment: Actually change this to the one below but my data extension is not pulling in the total sends.

Comment: SELECT count(*) AS TotalSent, SubscriberKey as EmailAddress, SubscriberKey

FROM _Sent

WHERE Domain LIKE '%exclaim-dev.com%' AND 

EventDate between '2018-01-01' and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

GROUP BY SubscriberKey

HAVING COUNT(*) > 0

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expetced result. All as formatted text, not images.